# Conver konvajs canvas to image and load these image to another canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, konvajs

I tried to build many konvajs canvas  and transform them to konva images.
And finally load these images to another canvas and show.

```
function main(){
    var total_konva_stage= createStage();
    var imagesLayer= new Konva.Layer();
    for (var key in  array){
         $(".tmpcontainer").remove();
         containerName = containerNameBase + key;
         $("#hidden_div").append("<div id='"+containerName+"'  class='tmpcontainer'></div>");

         var konva_stage =createcanvas(containerName);  //create a hidden dynamic div and bind this stage to it
         var img  = konva_stage .toDataURL("image/png");
         var imageObj = new Image();
         imageObj.src = img
         imageObj.onload = function() {
             callback_canvastoImg(imagesLayer, imageObj);
         };
     }
     total_konva_stage.add(imagesLayer);
     total_konva_stage.show();
     total_konva_stage.draw();
}
function callback_canvastoImg(imagesLayer, imageObj){
      var konva_image = new Konva.Image({imageObj}); 
      imagesLayer.add(konva_image );
}
```

What I think my results is  that "total_konva_stage" will have every separate **img**  that from konva_stage.

But I found my second **img**  will contain the first **img**  , my third **img** contain the first, second **img**

I have no idea now, please help.
Thanks

Comment: Jay - Is this working code? It looks like you cut it down too far for it to be viable. Can you review it please, and ideally make a working snippet that illustrates the issue? See my answer in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44591179/knovajs-html5-canvas-rotation-origin for how to provide a snippet that uses konvajs in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onload` function callback is asynchronous. It means it will be executed only after the whole array is processed.

So in this line: `callback_canvastoImg(imagesLayer, imageObj);` variable imageObj will refer to the LAST created image.

To avoid this you can:

1. Use modern js syntax of declaring variables (in case you should use something like `babel`)

   ```
   const imageObj = new Image();
   ```
2. You can define closure function for loop iteration. You just need to use `array.forEach` instead of for loop:

   ```
   array.forEach(function(item, key) {
     $(".tmpcontainer").remove();
     containerName = containerNameBase + key;
     $("#hidden_div").append("<div id='"+containerName+"'  class='tmpcontainer'></div>");

     var konva_stage =createcanvas(containerName);  //create a hidden dynamic div and bind this stage to it
     var img  = konva_stage .toDataURL("image/png");
     var imageObj = new Image();
     imageObj.src = img
     imageObj.onload = function() {
        callback_canvastoImg(imagesLayer, imageObj);
     };
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks lavrton, I found my root cause is the images not complete load before transform. I tested with following steps.

`
1. load images to konva.stage
2. Mouse go through all konva.stage in the screen. (images will really load)

3. Click a button to transform these konva.stage to img and load to an other  visible konva.stage
`